# How to get Domain name from URL using jquery..?

Tags: jquery

I have domain name for eq.

```
1) http://www.abc.com/search 
2) http://go.abc.com/work
```

I get only domain name from the above URL

Output like

```
1) http://www.abc.com/
2) http://go.abc.com/
```

how can I do?

Comment: The answer by sudhAnsu63 works for me :)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

### In a browser

You can leverage the browser's URL parser using an `<a>` element:

```
var hostname = $('<a>').prop('href', url).prop('hostname');
```

or without jQuery:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;
var hostname = a.hostname;
```

(This trick is particularly useful for resolving paths relative to the current page.)

### Outside of a browser (and probably more efficiently):

Use the following function:

```
function get_hostname(url) {
    var m = url.match(/^http:\/\/[^/]+/);
    return m ? m[0] : null;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
get_hostname("http://example.com/path");
```

This will return `http://example.com/` as in your example output.

### Hostname of the current page

If you are only trying the get the hostname of the current page, use `document.location.hostname`.

Comment: Thanks but I getting error .match not a function what will problem?

Comment: the first argument of the function must be a string.

Comment: url.match(/^http.?:\/\/[^/]+/) to support https

Comment: To Support Https,   var m = url.match(/^https?:\/\/[^/]+/);

Comment: Oops, this may produce unexpected results if **not a valid url**. The empty string or `'foobar'`turn into the hostname of the current page. `"http://e%ample.com"` turns into the empty string. It might help to verify `$('<a>').prop('href', url).prop('href') === url` but this may have weird edge cases too.

Answer (score 64):

This worked for me.

http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/get-current-url-javascript-jquery

```
$(location).attr('host');                        www.test.com:8082
$(location).attr('hostname');                    www.test.com
$(location).attr('port');                        8082
$(location).attr('protocol');                    http:
$(location).attr('pathname');                    index.php
$(location).attr('href');                        http://www.test.com:8082/index.php#tab2
$(location).attr('hash');                       #tab2
$(location).attr('search');                     ?foo=123
```

Comment: Very useful..  Just one minor correction.  $(location).attr('protocol');  returns the value with the colon ':'  For example http: or https:

Comment: $(location).attr('protocol');   returns with a colon(:) i.e. http:

Comment: More useful than any other comment

Answer (score 15):

Try like this.

```
var hostname = window.location.origin

If the URL is "http://example.com/path" then you will get  "http://example.com" as the result.
```

This won't work for local domains

```
When you have URL like "https://localhost/MyProposal/MyDir/MyTestPage.aspx" 
and your virtual directory path is "https://localhost/MyProposal/" 
In such cases, you will get "https://localhost".
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do this with plain js by using

1. `location.host` , same as `document.location.hostname`
2. <del>document.domain</del> Not recommended

Comment: `document.domain` is not the correct way of retrieving the current hostname; it's a setting used for [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Also, `location.host` is `document.location.hostname` ;-)

Answer (score 7):

You don't need jQuery for this, as simple javascript will suffice:

```
alert(document.domain);
```

See it in action:

```
console.log("Output;");  
console.log(location.hostname);
console.log(document.domain);
alert(window.location.hostname)

console.log("document.URL : "+document.URL);
console.log("document.location.href : "+document.location.href);
console.log("document.location.origin : "+document.location.origin);
console.log("document.location.hostname : "+document.location.hostname);
console.log("document.location.host : "+document.location.host);
console.log("document.location.pathname : "+document.location.pathname);
```

for more details click here [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

just append "http://" before domain name to get appropriate result.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a trick, by creating a `<a>`-element, then setting the string to the href of that `<a>`-element and then you have a [Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) you can get the hostname from.

You could either add a method to the String prototype:

```
String.prototype.toLocation = function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = this;
    return a;
};
```

and use it like this:
    `"http://www.abc.com/search".toLocation().hostname`

or make it a function:

```
function toLocation(url) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    return a;
};
```

and use it like this:
    `toLocation("http://www.abc.com/search").hostname`

both of these will output: `"www.abc.com"`

If you also need the protocol, you can do something like this:

```
var url = "http://www.abc.com/search".toLocation();
url.protocol + "//" + url.hostname
```

which will output: `"http://www.abc.com"`

Comment: The IE problem of blank hostnames on these fake <a> elements is a problem in other cases too. Some tricks/workarounds here, plus discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755943/ie-forgets-an-a-tags-hostname-after-changing-href

Answer (score 3):

While pure JavaScript is sufficient here, I still prefer the jQuery approach.  After all, the ask was to get the hostname **using jQuery**.

```
var hostName = $(location).attr('hostname');      // www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the url as well as the protocol used we can try the code below.

For example to get the domain as well as the protocol used (http/https).

`https://google.com`

You can use -

`host = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname+'/';`

It'll return you the protocol as well as domain name. `https://google.com/`

Answer (score 0):

```
var hostname = window.location.origin
```

Will not work for IE.
For IE support as well I would something like this:

```
var hostName = window.location.hostname;
var protocol = window.locatrion.protocol;
var finalUrl = protocol + '//' + hostname;
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code below it works fine with me.

example below is getting the host and redirecting to another page.

```
var host = $(location).attr('host');
window.location.replace("http://"+host+"/TEST_PROJECT/INDEXINGPAGE");
```