# IE forgets an A-Tag's hostname after changing HREF

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I set the `href`-Attribute of an `<a ...>`-Tag dynamically in a project. At some other point, I check the `<a>`'s DOM-Property called `hostname`, in order to figure out whether or not it's an internal link.

Basically, this is what happens.

```
<!--HTML-->
<a id="my" href="/my/first/link">MyLink</a>
<div id="log"></div>
```

And JS is:

```
// js
var a = document.getElementById( 'my' ),
    log = document.getElementById( 'log' );

log.innerHTML += a.hostname + '<br/>';

a.setAttribute('href',"/my/other/link");
log.innerHTML += a.hostname;
```

(cf. also this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RurQT/ )

As I set `d.href` to a relative path, I expect `d.hostname` to be unchanged - so the `log`-Div contains the same Hostname twice. This is correct in FF and Chrome.

However, InternetExplorer 7, 8 and 9 all insist that the second time, the hostname is empty.

I am especially confused, because the first link has been relative all along! I don't have any `<base href>` set, btw.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestion how I can make InternetExplorer update the "hostname"-Property of the `a`-DOM-Element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to stash and re-set it it seems:

```
var d = document.getElementById( 'my' ),
var h = d.hostname
d.setAttribute('href',"/my/other/link");
d.hostname = h
```

Comment: Seems like this is the only possibility, indeed. I have, however, in my case, decided to extend the check, so an empty `hostname`-string will be treated equally to `(d.hostname == location.hostname)`, which will work fine unless one has a base href set to another domain.

Comment: What about the `host` property (that includes the port)? Does it behave the same way?

Comment: Looks like `protocol` property is also affected but the lost value is `":"`, not an empty string.

Comment: The `host` and `port` properties are also affected (the lost value is an empty string for both).

Comment: Moreover, I've just got `protocol` to be `"about:"` and `pathname` to start with `"//"` in IE10. So it's better to reparse the URL from `href` via new anchor element.