# javascript How to check if a URL is same origin as current page?

Tags: javascript, url

How can I check if a specific URL string is from the same origin/ host as the current page? For example, if I wanted to bind to links, but only prevent default on links to the same host...

Answer (score 9):

This should be safe to use nowadays:

```js
function sameOrigin(a, b) {
    const urlA = new URL(a);
    const urlB = new URL(b);
    return urlA.origin === urlB.origin;
}

console.log(sameOrigin('https://stacksnippets.net', window.location))
```

Answer (score 4):

The Origin definiton from the RFC 6454:

> Roughly speaking, two URIs are part of the same
>      origin (i.e., represent the same principal) if they have the same
>      scheme, host, and port.

So we need to compare scheme, host, and port from two URIs, if they are the same, then these two URIs are the same origin.

A working code snippet:

```
function isOriginSameAsLocation(url) {
  var pageLocation = window.location;
  var URL_HOST_PATTERN = /(\w+:)?(?:\/\/)([\w.-]+)?(?::(\d+))?\/?/;
  var urlMatch = URL_HOST_PATTERN.exec(url) || [];
  var urlparts = {
      protocol:   urlMatch[1] || '',
      host:       urlMatch[2] || '',
      port:       urlMatch[3] || ''
  };

  function defaultPort(protocol) {
     return {'http:':80, 'https:':443}[protocol];
  }

  function portOf(location) {
     return location.port || defaultPort(location.protocol||pageLocation.protocol);
  }

  return !!(  (urlparts.protocol  && (urlparts.protocol  == pageLocation.protocol)) &&
              (urlparts.host     && (urlparts.host      == pageLocation.host))     &&
              (urlparts.host     && (portOf(urlparts) == portOf(pageLocation)))
          );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple snippet of jQuery that will only `preventDefault()` on events called when clicking a link to an external URL.

The logic for assessing the URL is:

1. Skip if local path
2. Skip if full URL and the host is the same

I think that will work for a lot of simple use-cases.

```js
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
  var hrefURL, pageURL;
  hrefURL = new URL(this.href);
  pageURL = new URL(window.location);
  if (!(href.startsWith("/") || hrefURL.host === pageURL.host)) {
    return e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you could [parse each link](https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561), and then compare the "hostname" component to that returned by [window.location.hostname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/hostname).

```js
;(function(){
    "use strict";
    
    var parseUrl = function(link){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = link;
        return a;
    };
    
    var isSameOrigin = function(url1,url2) {
        return (url1.hostname === url2.hostname);
    };
    
    var localClick = function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        alert('you clicked a local link');
    };
    
    var currentPage = window.location || window.document.location;

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
        
      var els = document.querySelectorAll("a");
      for (var i=0;i<els.length;i++) {
          var el = els[i];        
          var othercell = el.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling;
          var isLocal = isSameOrigin( parseUrl(el.href), currentPage );
          othercell.innerHTML = isLocal;
          if (isLocal) {
             // now bind to the element
             el.addEventListener('click',localClick);  
          }
      }
    
    });
  
})();
```

```css
th {
  text-align: left; background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>link</th>
      <th>is same origin?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><a href="http://varsity.com">Varsity</a></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><a href="http://stacksnippets.net">Stack Snippets</a></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><a href="http://jsfiddle.net">JS Fiddle</a></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><a href="http://null.jsbin.com">JS Bin</a></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>   
</table>
```

Here is the same code on js bin:

http://jsbin.com/cigewa/1/edit?js,output

Comment: In addition to the hostname, you need to check the protocol and port.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more modern version:

```js
function sameOrigin(uri1, uri2=false){
  if(!uri2) uri2 = window.location.href;
  uri1 = new URL(uri1);
  uri2 = new URL(uri2);
  if(uri1.host !== uri2.host) return false;
  if(uri1.port !== uri2.port) return false;
  if(uri1.protocol !== uri2.protocol) return false;
  return true;
}

console.log(sameOrigin("https://google.com"));
console.log(sameOrigin("https://stacksnippets.net"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the link for your current page is:

```
<a href="current.html" id="redirect">HomePage</a>
```

And you are clicking on a random link:

```
<a href="random.html" id="rdm">HomePage</a>
```

Then write a javascript function as:

```js
function check(){
  if(document.getElementById("rdm").toString().indexOf("current")<0){
                 
    // do something  
         
    /*If it returns a negative value it means that the link we
     clicked does not contain the string 'current'(as our host is 
     current.html) i.e.the link is not our host link */
  else{
  
            // do something else
      }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: current.html is not a "host" and why use toString()? What if the text was in another attribute then?

Comment: toString() is done simply because indexOf() is a method of String object.

Answer (score 0):

while the answer from didxga should be less effort on the client side the answer from code monk brings me to a cleaner solution.

```
function doSomething(url) {
  // assuming we are in a function where we want to check the same origin
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  if (link.host !== location.host) {
    alert('url is invalid');
    return;
  }

  // do something...
}
```

**Note** that I'm using `window.location` with `location`. You may want to support browsers where this implementation is not working or have a location variable in a parent scope.

Comment: I really liked this answer, unfortunately it does not work in IE11:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755943/ie-forgets-an-a-tags-hostname-after-changing-href

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short but effective solution I came up with after discovering that the "check the host of an anchor tag" method doesn't work in IE11:

```
  function sameSite(uri) {
    var matches = uri.match(/^(https?:)?\/\/([^\/]+)/);
    if (!matches) {
      // If URI is not absolute or protocol-relative then it is always same-origin
      return true;
    }
    return window.location.host === matches[2];
  };
```

This returns true if the uri references the same site (same host and port) as the current page. Cross-browser implementation, valid at least back to IE11.

Regarding port numbers, this will match as long as the URIs are consistent about not explicitly specifying the port number when it is 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS), which is generally the case, so I didn't bother with special logic to handle a default port when it is explicit versus not explicit. I don't think that's likely to come up in practice, but there are other answers here that include it if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement this system, like so (note: not tested, typed directly into the browser):

```js
const checkURL(string) => {
    return new URL(string).host === location.host;
}
// to replace all <a> tags with the href "#invalid" if the hosts don't match
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
   document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(tag => {
      // you don't have to have it go to a #*, but you could set it to a page that indicates the URL is not allowed.
      tag.href = checkURL(tag.href) ? tag.href : "#invalid";
  });
});
// to make links that go to the same host not do anything
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
    document.querySelectorALl("a").forEach(tag => {
        tag.href = checkURL(tag.href) ? "#" : tag.href
    })
})
```

Answer (score -3):

You can get the current page's host IE example.com from `http://example.com/hello-world` with `window.location.host`. With that you can see if a string, IE the URL to test, contains that string.

```
   function sameOrigin( url ) {
        var host = window.location.host;
        var sameOrigin = url.indexOf(host);
        if ( sameOrigin >= 0 ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you returning `false` if `sameOrigin < 0`?

Comment: undefined is falsey :p