# How to check if a URL is same origin as current page and/or worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

There's a similar question here

[javascript How to check if a URL is same origin as current page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374766/javascript-how-to-check-if-a-url-is-same-origin-as-current-page)

Unfortunately it doesn't specify that answers must work in both a page and a worker so none of the answers work in a worker.

In particular I'm trying to use the fetch API to fetch images in a way that works as automatically as possible. When an image is fetched I want to set the mode to `cors` but only if the URL is not the same origin. I need to know how to do that in both a page context and a worker context.

Pseudo code

```js
function loadImageBitmap(url) {
  const options = {};
  if (urlIsNotSameOrigin(url)) {
    options.mode = 'cors'; 
  }
  return fetch(url, options)
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw response;
    }
    return response.blob();
  }).then((blob) => {
    return global.createImageBitmap(blob);
  });
}

function urlIsNotSameOrigin(url) {
  // what do I put here?
}

// examples
async function main() {
  const bitmaps = Promise.all([
    'https://notsamedomain.com/foo.jpg',
    '../relative/image.png',
    '/absolute/thing.jpg',
    '//other/absolute/thing.jpg',
    'https://samedomain.com/bar.gif',
  ].map(loadImageBitmap));
}
```

Most of the solutions I've seen are to make an anchor `<a>` element, assign the `src` property and then read it.  But anchors don't exist in workers.  The `URL` object doesn't seem to handle relative resources like the anchor does.

Comment: By "workers" do you mean web workers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the *URL()* constructor and the anchor *<a>* element is that the *URL()* constructor is not a Node nor is it attached to a particular *Document* object, and thus doesn't have a [*baseURI*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI) it can hook on.

So what you need in order to make the *URL()* constructor behave the same as an anchor *<a>* element is to pass a *baseURI* as the [second argument of the constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL#Parameters).

This means that in a document `new URL(uri, document.baseURI)` would return the same URL properties as `Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {href: uri})`, as long as the *URI* produced is a valid one.

Now, in a Worker we still don't have access to a *Node*'s *baseURI* either, and it's quite unclear which you want to hook on.

In most cases, you can simply use `self.location.href` as a base URI, and that might actually be what you want if you are going to fetch same-origin resources, but if you do initialize your Worker from a blobURL, you may have to pass it from the main scope, just like I had to do in StackSnippet®'s over-protected iframe.

```js
// init worker from a blobURI...
const worker_url = getWorkerURL(worker_script);
const worker = new Worker(worker_url);
worker.onmessage = e => console.log(e.data);

worker.postMessage({
  // we pass the base URL
  base: 'https://samedomain.com/foo.html',
  uris: [
    'https://notsamedomain.com/foo.jpg',
    '../relative/image.png',
    '/absolute/thing.jpg',
    '//other/absolute/thing.jpg',
    'https://samedomain.com/bar.gif'
    ]
});

//__MISC__________
// gets our Worker's blobURL based on a Blob made
// from a <script> element textContent
function getWorkerURL(el) {
  const content = el.textContent;
  const blob = new Blob([content], {type: 'application/javascript'});
  return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
```

```html
<script id="worker_script" type="worker_script">
  onmessage = e => {
    const d = e.data;
    
    // if we weren't in a null origined iframe's blobURI we could do
    //const self_url = new URL(location.href)
    // but here we pass the fake base domain
    const self_url = new URL(d.base);
    const sameorigins = d.uris.filter( uri => {
      try { // wrap in a try-catch, invalids throw
        const url = new URL(uri, self_url);
        return url.origin === self_url.origin;
      } catch(e) { return false; }
    })
    postMessage(sameorigins);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: IIRC blobs have the same restrictions meaning a blob URL is actually considered a different domain and so requires cors permissions to do almost anything

Comment: @gman yes, except for other blobURIs from the same origin, that is either created from the main doc or from the Worker itself (and maybe from other Worker created from the same main doc, but I never tried that scenario and don't know browser support). So you can do from a *blobURIed* Worker fetch(URL.createObjectURL(blob)) and it should work.