# Get domain name from a url stred in variable using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$url = 'http://hostname.com/folder/folder2/test.php?id=243432432424243';
```

from the variable above can i have like as follow:

```
$finalUrl = 'http://hostname.com';
```

if yes than please answer this.

Comment: DUPLICATE..Duplicate everywhere... -> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815559/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url-using-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815559/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $url = 'http://hostname.com/folder/folder2/test.php?id=243432432424243';

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = $url;

var $finalUrl = a.protocol + '//' + a.hostname;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getBaseURL() {
    var url = location.href;  // entire url including querystring - also: window.location.href;
    var baseURL = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('/', 14));
    if (baseURL.indexOf('http://localhost') != -1) {
        // Base Url for localhost
        var url = location.href;  // window.location.href;
        var pathname = location.pathname;  // window.location.pathname;
        var index1 = url.indexOf(pathname);
        var index2 = url.indexOf("/", index1 + 1);
        var baseLocalUrl = url.substr(0, index2);
        return baseLocalUrl + "/";
    }
    else {
        // Root Url for domain name
        return baseURL + "/";
    }

}
```