# How to get URL domain without path

Tags: jquery

[image]

> $(this).attr('href')

I know that this code brings me to the link as a whole
But I want to just get on https://www.facebook.com

Comment: here is what you need:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815559/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url-using-jquery

Comment: *When* do you want this? And is this the address of the page, or the `href` of an `<a>` element in the page? What is `$(this)`, in context?

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
$(this).attr('href').split("/")[2]
```

Comment: Did not work with me
Can you give me an example of a way to get a link http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Maybe, @Abdallha, if *you* show some representative ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) code to show what exactly you're doing, or trying to do, we can offer better answers. As it is your question is far too vague to be properly answered.

Comment: I want to get a link to the page as in the picture
Link without the original's

Comment: @Abdallhadagga I'm not following you... If you need a domain of your current position you can try with this: alert(document.domain);

Comment: I did not mean to offend, but do not speak English

Comment: @Abdallhadagga it's ok... Try to explain your problem as best as you can, give us part of your code, your thoughts, your final goal...

Comment: please you cann add me on facebook
fb.com/abdallhadagga