# Get current path without final file name

Tags: java, jquery

i try to get a path from a scriptfile for using inside the script themself but without the final filename.

For Example:

http://www.domain.com/folder/

all my trieing with "window.location" dont work, at my tests, i get 
"http://www.domain.com"
or
"final_filename.php"

How can i get the path without the last final_filename with all subfolders in the fastes way?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815559/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pathParts = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var path = window.location.pathname.replace(pathParts[pathParts.length-1],'');
```

Comment: "pathParts.replace is not a function " !?

Comment: window.location.pathname.replace, try again )

Comment: in the result i miss the main domain - result for http://www.test.com/text.php is "/" !?

Comment: window.location.host + path ... or window.location.href